# Failed at adding light kits to fans

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan

I bought a house that has a lot of ceiling fans but none with lights. They're on dimmer switches as well. I decided to add light kits to two of the fans, a Hunter fan and a Hampton Bay fan (sorry don't know model numbers). I easily found and attached the white/white and blue/black on both fans, having to strip the wires inside the fans and using wire connector caps to attach the light kit wires. I was not able to get the lights to turn on after either install, and one of the fans now hums but doesn't spin. I checked the reverse switch to make sure it wasn't in a neutral position. Is it possible the motor broke during install? Is it a capacitor issue? Should I try to salvage the non working fan or replace the whole unit. Is there a secret step I missed when installing the light kits? I know almost nothing about this kind of thing except for what I just learned in this forum and from some YouTube videos. Appreciate the help!

Comment: If it worked before, it's time to rollback your changes and get it to a working state.  It sounds like there is something you are not understanding about the hookup.  Probably our next step is get some photos.

Comment: Check your splice at the wire nut ,may have pushed wire out and not good contact .

Comment: Do the light kits have a pull cord? The dimmer would slow the fan as well as dim the lights....is this what you wanted?

Comment: I revisited the splice by stripping the wires to about 3/4 inch of exposed wire and doing the wire nuts again. Nothing happened, fan goes on, lights do nothing. There is a pull cord on the fan, and another pull cord on the light kit. I've tried every variation of pulling cords while having the dimmer switch on and on the highest setting. Could the fact that there's a dimmer at all make this a more difficult install (ie should I just hire an electrician)?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The "light" wire in the base of each fan was not connected to anything. Brought in an electrician who hooked them up, connected the light kits and voila, let there be light. Nothing I read on this forum or others mentioned the possibility that when the fans were installed without lights the electrician could have just left the light wire disconnected. Great to know for the future. Appreciate everyone's suggestions! Glad to know it wasn't anything I did wrong.